# Windows Phone 8.1 Speech Synthesizer Access Denied?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to build an app that speaks to users when they press a button.

The speech synthesizer code is as follows

```
 Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer x = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
      var stream = await x.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(someString);
      var mediaElement = new MediaElement();
      mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
      mediaElement.Play();
```

While this code worked in a different app it does not work with this project. I keep receiving the following error.

```
  +     e   {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. Access is denied. at Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer..ctor()  at TalkingWalkingMaps.ManeuverDisplayer.<DisplayManeuver>d__0.MoveNext()}    System.Exception {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}
```

I read online that I had to remove the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Speech\CurrentUserLexicon value
from my registry using regedit but this did not work.

Can Anyone Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out the issue stems from the App Manifest file. Although not intuitive at first glance the Microphone Capability must be enabled for Speech Synthesizer to work. 
[image]

Comment: Now that is just weird, hoping it fixes my issue. Hit this last night